# How can I disable the warning without exclude? in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

How can I disable the warning without exclude? in angular

```
`Warning: /home/renat/Desktop/front/node_modules/rilata/src/app/controller/constants.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.

`
```

I don't want to write files every time
`

```
Warning: /home/renat/Desktop/front/node_modules/rilata/src/app/service/error-types.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.
`
```

I do not know how to use it

Comment: Show your tsconfig.json